# Hamburger menu goes under text and image

Tags: html, css

I have tried to add a hamburger menu to my web page but it keeps going under the images and texts. I changed the z-index with different numbers but it still doesn't work.the menu it self has no problem and works somoothly but when I shrink the page, the images and the texts are on the menu if anyone knows please give a suggestion. Thank you

```css
#menu__toggle {
  opacity: 0;
}

#menu__toggle:checked+.menu__btn>span {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#menu__toggle:checked+.menu__btn>span::before {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}

#menu__toggle:checked+.menu__btn>span::after {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

#menu__toggle:checked~.menu__box {
  left: 0 !important;
}

.menu__btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.menu__btn>span,
.menu__btn>span::before,
.menu__btn>span::after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #08ebfc;
  transition-duration: .25s;
}

.menu__btn>span::before {
  content: '';
  top: -8px;
}

.menu__btn>span::after {
  content: '';
  top: 8px;
}

.menu__box {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -100%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 80px 0;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #ECEFF1;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
  transition-duration: .25s;
}

.menu__item {
  display: block;
  padding: 12px 24px;
  color: #333;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition-duration: .25s;
}

.menu__item:hover {
  background-color: #CFD8DC;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
  <div class="hamburger-menu">
    <!--this is the part for the menu-->
    <input id="menu__toggle" type="checkbox" />
    <label class="menu__btn" for="menu__toggle">
                  <span></span>
                </label>

    <ul class="menu__box">
      <li><a class="menu__item" href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a class="menu__item" href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a class="menu__item" href="#">Team</a></li>
      <li><a class="menu__item" href="#">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a class="menu__item" href="#">Twitter</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <h1 class="neonText" style="text-align:center; padding:3% auto 1% auto;">TRANSFORMERS</h1>
  <div class="container">
    <img src="dece.jpg" alt="Decepticon logo" style="width:100%;">
    <h1 class="h1-d">DECEPTICONS</h1>
    <div class="content">

    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, it goes up the image and text, there might be interfernce with some other css codes.